# ASP.NET & VB.net html ID adding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to make a big table with 100 cells and I did that by using the "insert table" option but when you do that the td's have no ID's to them so I can't talk with them in code. Now I'm just making a small part of what will later be a table with 1000's of cells.

I was thinking of something like:

```
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 100
        (What do I put here?).Attributes.Add(ClientID, "td" & i.ToString)
    Next
```

My HTML looks like:

```
<table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td id="td1" runat="server">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td id="td2" runat="server">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
```

but then I have 100 td's not just 3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You dont want 1000's of cells. The page will never render in time or the user will just ignore it anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. You have to make the table accessible to the server side.

```
<table class="style1" runat="server" id="theTable">
</table>


Dim row as New TableRow()
theTable.Rows.Add(row)

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 100
  Dim cell as New TableCell()
  cell.Attributes.Add(ClientID, "td" & i.ToString)
  row.Cells.Add(cell)
Next
```

Comment: @StingyJack Had to make a few changes because it gave me an error when adding the row telling me that it had to be a htmlrow and same thing whith the cell but works great thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, was doing from memory and Craig's link. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with StingyJack's comment.  However, if you REALLY do need that many cells, have you looked into the Table control (available in the Visual Studio Toolbox)?

I just +1 StingyJack's answer...this is what I was preparing as well...